# Certificate for Development and Production is Disabled

Tags: ios, objective-c, certificate

In our developer account,Certificate tab the Development and Production  is Disabled

[image]

[image]

What is the problem?

Comment: This is very odd, double check that your subscription hasnt expired and you are logged in as a user that has the permissions to do this (Admin or Agent). Finally I would contact Apple support as they are the only ones likely to be able to fix it. I have checked mine and it is working so looks like the portal is OK

Comment: @AdamRichardson Our account is renewed one moths ago...
15 days back i have added certificate to that account only,but now its disabled